# MVC Linking to views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

New to MVC so learning (in a frustrated kind of way as finding simple things that used to take 5 minutes in webforms have become over complicated)

So I've set up a solution in VS2015 which comes with the pre-requisite Account section.

I've also set up tables in a database and built the entities from that (producing some `CRUD`)

So I can log in and get to my AccountHome view (`return View("AccountHome")` in the `AccountController`)

From my `AccountHome` page, I can navigate to another view using a seperate controller
(`@Html.ActionLink("Add Foods", "Create", "fad_userFoods", new { id = ViewBag.userID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })`)

Here I do some form entry and the data is successfully added to the database but here is where my problem lies. After data entry I want to go back to the `AccountHome` view

So in my `fad_userFoodsControler` I have this code
(`return RedirectToAction("AccountHome","Account")`)
 - says resource cannot be found!!!

In my `AccountController` I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AccountHome()
{
    return View();
}
```

In my `AccountViewModels` I have this code:

```
public class AccountHomeViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in my `AccountHome.cshtml` page I have this declared at the top (`@model FiveADayMVC2.Models.AccountHomeViewModel`)

Where am I going wrong? Looked at numerous posts and they all do it this way. I know the view exists because I can get to it from login. Yet, if I type the url manually (i.e. my url followed by `/Account/AccountHome`) it's not found either???

It's going to be a lack of understanding on my part but where?

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: Can you clean up your question by indenting your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) This will navigate the user to the view of a specific action in a given controller.

```
if(actionSuccess)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

UPDATE:

Make sure you have a controller for HttpGet

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AccountHome()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult AccountHome()
{
    return View();
}
```

Since you added [HttpPost] to the controller it will be the one executed after a post was made on "AccountHome"

Comment: Hi John, I do use it (RedirectToAction("AccountHome","Account")) 
AccountHome is a new view that I have set up. 
If I use a view which was set up by the default solution it works (e.g. RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword","Account")) 
Just doesn't work for the AccountHome view I've set up. :-(

Comment: I can confirm that that view exists. I know it does because (not only checking it visually on the server) when I log in, I navigate to the page successfully using the following code:
return View("AccountHome")